# Why can't I propose tag wikis on meta?

Tags: support, tag-wiki, meta

I know there is an edit queue which can fill up, but us mortal users are not informed of this circumstance so maybe this is the problem.

I definitely can propose tag wiki edits in the main site so maybe main and meta have independent queues and only the main one has been serviced. Or maybe there's something about editing tags on meta that makes it different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like meta tags are special and will be (in the future) [inherited from meta.so](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92219/proposing-tag-wiki-creation-does-not-work-on-meta-sites).